# Is there a way to merge identical protocols between frameworks?

Tags: swift

I'm working a project that has multiple components.  Some of those components will need to be re-useable between apps -- the apps are related but cannot themselves be merged for business reasons.  Thankfully the problem below isn't actually going to cause me issues, but I'm highly curious about how I'd solve it.  Because someday I may just need to implement the following pattern.

So assuming I've got a CocoaPod named `Foo` and another named `Bar`.  `Foo` reports to it's delegates using objects that implement the `Foo.BussinessLogic` protocol.  `Bar` just happens to have an identical `Bar.BussinessLogic` protocol.  I can write objects that conform to both protocols readily enough, but other than directly making `Foo` conform to `Bar.BussinessLogic`, how do I connect to the two without writing a pair of wrappers around each whose only job is to say `item as! Bar.BussinessLogic` when Foo sends a message to bar, and vice versa?

Comment: "how do I connect to the two" What does that even mean? I don't see what the problem is. A table view controller conforms to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource, but there's no need to go around casting it all the time. It just _is_.

Comment: @matt the issue is that even if the two protocols are identical, a Bar.BussinessLogic implimenting object would not be accepted as a parameter that calls for Foo.BussinessLogic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the protocols share a bunch of methods, then my instinct would be to have them both conform to a common protocol in a third library that they both can depend on.

In Swift you can't just trick the compiler and say "trust me, they have the same methods".

However, I'm not sure if that answers your question since the types in your question are so nebulous. There are lots of other possible solutions. It depends on the situation.